# Почему и как JS самостоятельно изменяет числа?

Tags: javascript, числа

В [learn.js](https://learn.javascript.ru/number#netochnye-vychisleniya) приводится пример:

```js
console.log( 9999999999999999 ); // покажет 10000000000000000
```

В учебнике говорится, что причина такому поведению в том, что отведенных 52 бит на цифры до десятичной запятой не хватает. Я не понимаю. По идее, если не хватает памяти, число наоборот должно уменьшаться, а не наоборот - увеличиваться как это происходит в примере выше (было 16, стало 17 знаков).

P.S. И кстати, насколько я знаю, если числу не хватает отведенной ему памяти, должно выводить `Infinity`. Почему в этом случае не выводится `Infinity`?

Может кто-нибудь получше объяснить как это работает?

Comment: Infinity это некоторое виртуальное число (математическое понятие) фактически получить его путем счетчика не возможно (простой пример: Infinity - Infinity дает NAN что не могло быть если бы это было числом) Что касается нехватки памяти и уменьшения числа то тут (число не обязано уменьшаться) числа огрубляются в ту или иную сторону с некоторой погрешностью речь идет о битах а не о байтах и конечно про мантису если дробные числа. Польза от Infinity заключается в том что оно позволяет взять наибольшее из положительных или наименьшее из отрицательный чисел - что очень полезно в алгоритмах.

Comment: @Daniil Loban _фактически получить его путем счетчика не возможно_ если ввести достаточно большое число, то можно - `console.log( 1e500 ); //Infinity`

Comment: @Daniil Loban Скорее всего, как я понимаю, здесь дело в том, что введенное число (9999999999999999) больше максимально безопасного в JS. `console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER); //9007199254740991` Значение чисел которых больше максимально безопасного числа, могут иметь неточности - округляться и т.д. А `Infinity` выводится, когда число явно превышает отведенную ему память - 64 бита.

Comment: Да, был не прав (можно получить путем сложения, что немного абсурдно - нельзя досчитать до бесконечности), инфинити начинается с 1e309 где-то, на мой вгляд это уже косяк языка, хотя вряд ли кто-то орудует такими числами в реальности. По поводу округления если найду хороший пример добавлю в ответ

Comment: https://msiter.ru/tutorials/javascript/js_numbers на мой взгляд самое понятное объяснение